# Flask-Login: how to compare current_user to user id in a relation?

Tags: comparison, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I'm writing an app with SQLAlchemy backend, that has a model with a field defined as follows:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class MyObject(db.Model):
    user = relationship(User, primaryjoin=user_id==User.id)
```

Users are logged in by Flask-Login.

In the views I experience somehow peculiar behavior:

```
     36     import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
---> 37     if theobject.user != current_user:
     38         abort(403)
```

This always fails with 403.

```
ipdb> theobject.user                                                                                                       
<User emes [emes@test.com]>
ipdb> current_user                                                                                                      
<User emes [emes@test.com]>
ipdb> theobject.user == current_user                                                                                       
False
```

Why does it happen? Is implementing `User.__eq__` the proper way to go here?

Answer (score 1):

Can you do comparison based on Ids?
For example

```
theobject.user.id == current_user.id
# or

theobject.user.email == current_user.email
```

Comment: Sure I can, but comparison of the objects seems more intuitive. Also, Django does it by default, and here I'm fishing for a reason why it doesn't happen here too.